# Outputting lines from a file containing a specific string

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, output

I'm a beginner at Python 3 and I kind of need help with a problem. I'm to output each line in a file `filename` containing string `target`, preceded by the line number.

I have tried to test what I came up with but IDLE keeps throwing up an error message saying "No such file or directory:" even though I have put song lyrics into a file etc.

So here is what I have:

```
def SearchFile (filename, target):
    filehandle = open ( filename, "r" )
    linenumber = 0
    while True :
        line = filehandle.readline ()
        if line == "":
            break
        linenumber += 1
        print ("%3i - %10i - %s" % (linenumber, target, line) )
```

So, can anyone tell me if I'm going about this the right way or making a very stupid mistake?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: *“No such file or directory”* means that the file could not be found. So the file path is probably wrong.

Comment: Where is the file stored? What is Python's working directory? If you just ran Idle from the start menu, it's "C:\Python33" (probably)

Answer (score 0):

As @poke says, "No such file or directory" means that the file could not be found. So the file path is probably wrong

Aside from that, you do have another issue - you don't check for the presence of `target` in the line that you print

```
def searchFile(filename, target):
  with open(filename) as infile:
    for linenum, line in enumerate(infile):
      if target in line:
        print("%3i - %10i - %s" % (linenumber, target, line))
```